# What approach should I follow if I need to select a data 'EXCEPT' some other bunch of data?

Tags: sql, t-sql, filtering, where-clause

What approach should I follow to construct my SQL query if I need to select a data exepct some other data?

For example, my

I want so select all the data from the data-base **EXCEPT** this result-set:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.MarketTYpe = 'EmergingMarkets'
AND IsBigOne = 1
AND MarketVolume = 'MIDDLE'
AND SomeClass = 'ThirdClass'
```

Should I use

- NOT IN (the aboe result set)
- Or shoudl I get INVERSE of the conditions like != inseat of = etc.
- Or ?

Can you advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) construct?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.MarketTYpe = 'EmergingMarkets'
AND IsBigOne = 1
AND MarketVolume = 'MIDDLE'
AND SomeClass = 'ThirdClass'
```

Note that `EXCEPT` and `NOT EXISTS` give the same query plan using "left anti semi joins".

`NOT IN (subquery with above)` may *not* give correct results if there are NULL values in the sub-query, hence I wouldn't use

I would avoid negation in the WHERE clause because it isn't readable straight away
As the comments show on Michael's answer...

For more on "all rows except some rows", see these:

- [Combining datasets with EXCEPT versus checking on IS NULL in a LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249891/combining-datasets-with-except-versus-checking-on-is-null-in-a-left-join/4249958#4249958)
- [To take out those dept who has no employees assigned to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545742/to-take-out-those-dept-who-has-no-employees-assigned-to-it/4545767#4545767)
- [SQL NOT IN possibly performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774259/sql-not-in-causing-performance-issues/6774960#6774960)
- (DBA.SE) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/the-use-of-not-logic-in-relation-to-indexes/4010#4010

Comment: Do I need to concern about the performance? compared to usage of <> instead of =, etc?

Comment: @pencilcake: EXCEPT and NOT EXISTS will be semantically correct and quicker (it is a semi join to find the row to omit). Using negation in the WHERE clause in non-Sargable too

Comment: +1 - the SARGable aspect is possibly the most persuasive argument of which to use

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and probably fastest here is to simply invert the conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.MarketTYpe <> 'EmergingMarkets'
  OR IsBigOne <> 1
  OR MarketVolume <> 'MIDDLE'
  OR SomeClass <> 'ThirdClass'
```

This is likely to use lots fewer resources than doing a `NOT IN()`.  You may wish to benchmark them to be certain, but the above is likely to be faster.

Comment: @drdwilcox Why? Doing `MarketType <> 'EmergingMarkets' OR IsBigOne <> 1` would return `MarketType = 'EmergingMarkets'` when `IsBigOne = 0`. that's not how I understand the OP's desired result

Comment: @drdwilcox switching to `OR` would drastically change the logic here. I don't think that's what the OP intends at all.

Comment: drdwilcox is right, you are just wanting a row where ANY of the 4 columns do not match (assuming original posters logic was stated correctly and we consider that AND clause in the OP to really mean a SQL AND) deMorgans rule on putting a Not thru the logic (A & B & C & D) => ! (A & B & C & D) => !A or !B or !C or !D

Comment: @Michael - get there in the end :) can +1 it now :)

Comment: @gbn I'm kind of inclined to agree.

Answer (score 2):

What database engine?

Minus operator in [ORACLE](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Minus)
Except operator in [SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT IN because that makes it clear that you want the set in the main select statement excluding the subset in the NOT IN select statement.

Comment: What makes you think this will be slower? The query optimizer may generate the same execution plan. You have to test all approaches to determine which one is faster.

Comment: NOT IN isn't always correct is there are NULL values in the subquery. Generally, NOT IN is to be avoided because of this: use NOT EXISTS or EXCEPT to be both *correct* and consistent

Comment: I didn't know about EXCEPT so that was great to learn. However, I think it's more accurate to say that NOT IN may produce _unexpected_, rather than incorrect, results if the set contains NULL values. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values

Answer (score 1):

I like gbn's answer, but another way of doing it can be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT (table1.MarketTYpe = 'EmergingMarkets'
AND IsBigOne = 1
AND MarketVolume = 'MIDDLE'
AND SomeClass = 'ThirdClass')
```